# undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass for IntegrationTest that fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a not-null constraint on a column. I have an `IntegrationTest` test case that `post`s an instance without that column. **My goal is to assert that response code returned is 400.**

My first try was:

```
test "should fail if no context" do
  post trips_url, params: { trip: { state: @trip.state } }
  assert_response 400
end
```

But this fails with `Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: trips.context:...`.

Which I don't really understand. Isn't `post` something like an HTTP client, and so it shouldn't be affected by the exceptions thrown in the controller?

But anyway, next I tried:

```
test "should fail if no context" do
  assert_raises(ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation) do
    post trips_url, params: { trip: { state: @trip.state } }
  end
  assert_response 400
end
```

But this fails with `` Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass ``, as if `response_code` wasn't set since an exception is thrown.

So, my question: How to achieve my goal? When testing an endpoint, I don't really care about what exceptions were thrown; I care about what response it's returned. So, **how to assert on the response in the case of a failure?**

I'm using `Rails 5.1.4`.

Comment: It depends on how does your controller code look like are you rescuing the `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation` in controller and then returning a bad_request ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But I've tested it manually and it does respond with 400. My goal is to assert on the HTTP response code _even if_ my code threw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if your controller is rescuing the ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation and rendering the 400 ? I imagine controller and spec to be something like below

Controller code

```
class User < ApplicationController
   def create
    .....
   rescue ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation => e
    render text: e.message, status: :bad_request 
  end
end
```

Spec code

```
it 'POST with null data returns bad request' do
  post to/user/path
  expect(response.code).to eq '400'
end
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Currently, my goal is not to find a way to return 400; my goal is to assert on the HTTP response code even if the code threw an exception. I've tested it manually & I know the response code is 400. Now, I want to write a test case that checks that. I want something like `assert_response` but that works even if an exception was thrown.